# What to do if extern "C" include collides with Qt libraries?

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces, ffmpeg, extern

In my case, I'm experimenting with QtMultimedia and libffmpeg as decoder.
Imported ffmpeg as extern "C", but the ffmpeg's AVPixelFormat collides with QVideoFrame's PixelFormat.

Exact error:

> 'AVPixelFormat' : is not a member of 'QVideoFrame'

Does anyone know a possible solution?

EDIT: Code parts.

Part 1: [Qt VideoWidget Sample](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/multimedia-videowidget.html)

Part 2: Usage of libffmpeg, based on [dranger tutorial](https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial)

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-In-Namespace - sounds like you can compile Qt using a namespace for their classes which will probably solve your issue

Comment: The enum in QVideoFrame is “PixelFormat”. Your variable is “AVPixelFormat”. I don’t see how that should clash (and the error message doesn’t suggest it does). Add the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the following line in the FFmpeg's `pixfmt.h`:

`#define PixelFormat AVPixelFormat`

You can try the following trick then:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

#undef PixelFormat
#include <qt headers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't blindly extern "C" the headers if they contain C++ code. Even if you make it past that collision you're going to run into problems at link time when your calls try to link to the "C" symbols but the ffmpeg library exports them with C++ linkage.

If you're trying to export C symbols, my advice would be to create a wrapper function that exports C but makes the C++ calls into the library.

Comment: afaik, ffmpeg is pure C. What I'm trying just now, several days before I wanted to compile Qt for VS2013. And, just as duselbär said, will try to compile it with namespace settings.